# Functions don't execute in the order I expect when using setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

I have this code where I am using two javascript functions that do some manipulating for me. One function does some calculation but calls the other function before doing anything else. When the other function returns to it, it is supposed to do the final calculations.

**The problem:** The call to the other function is not executing properly. Even before the second function returns the first function executes completely.
  **code:**

```
firstfunction{

        secondfunction();

        do something more nothing related to second
     }

secondfunction(){

           setTimeout(func1(){
               do something independently
                 then call func1 depending on some condition
               },time);     
         }
```

second function is used somewhere else also and is working fine.

**My question:**
   I used this code thinking that the first function will not execute before second function executes completely. Is it right? Isn't this the way javascript functions should run? The first function executes completely before second returns. I am sure of this because after second returns the position for the graphic first is supposed to place that graphic on screen. But the first executes completely and the graphic is placed awkwardly on screen and viewer can see it moving to right position given by the loop of second. Is `setTimeout` causing this problem?
Please help.

Comment: Does `secondfunction()` call `func1()` or `firstfunction()`?

Comment: Can you post real code instead of sudo code?

Comment: @matzahboy: I know a real code could help better but in my case the problem was setTimeout. The code is too big. Just wanted to keep the problem statement clean. It's been solved though. Thanks for the concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you use `setTimeout`. `setTimeout` will make it asynchronous. Execution of second function will be completed after setting the interval and execution-flow will go back to first function.  So you have to split your first function and make a third function which will have the final steps. This third function has to be invoked from the `setTimeout` handler.

```
     function firstfunction(){

        secondfunction(params);

     }

     function secondfunction(params){

           setTimeout(func1(){
               do something independently
                    then call thirdfunction depending on some condition
               },time);     
     }

     function thirdfunction(params){
         do something more nothing related to second
     }
```

In this method you have to pass everything as parameters from one function to other.

You can also do this in a different way by making third one a callback function. This way you can make everything in the scope of firstfunction available for thirdfunction.

```
     function firstfunction{

        secondfunction(thirdfunction);

        function thirdfunction(){
            do something more nothing related to second
        }

     }

     function secondfunction(callback){

           setTimeout(func1(){
               do something independently
                 then call callback depending on some condition
               },time);     
     }
```

Comment: the first one seems to me an easier solution. I will try that and write back if it helps. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: is it possible that i can call the func1 directly? 'cause it's and inner function.

Comment: yes : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/H6qUn/1/ . But make sure that it won't create infinite loop.

Comment: problem solved. Thanks a lot.  created a call to the third function inside timeout func1's ending.calling func1 directly from first function didn't work. is that what you meant? by your last comment? cause again, isn't its scope(func1's scope) limited to secondfunction?

Answer (score 0):

> *"Even before the second function returns the first function executes completely."*

No, in fact the second function returns immediately after it calls `setTimeout()` - it does *not* wait for the timeout to occur. The `func1()` function that you pass to `setTimeout()` will be called later after the specified timeout delay, but meanwhile execution continues with whatever follows the `setTimeout()` call (in this case the end of the function follows, so it returns to the first function and then the rest of the first function continues). To put it another way, `setTimeout()` does not pause execution.

If you need something to happen *after* the timeout you need to either place it in the function you pass to `setTimeout()` or call it from that function.

Comment: thanks for the solution, i tried it by putting an if statement inside the setTimeout function. The if can run only when first function is called i.e. its condition is enabled through first function only. And although it is running as it should the motion it gives to the graphics are shaky. It is probably the browser. Thanks for the solution anyways. I think i will have to find out some other way to keep the motions clean.